# Linux Kernel Programming, how to get information?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm a newbie on Linux programming and I don't know exactly where I can get information of functions for example. There is a directory Documentations in my sources. But I can't find semaphore stuff there for example. Is there a documentation for all the function somewhere in the sources? Or not obligatorily?

Comment: Is it actually kernel programming? If it is, you better not do it (as a beginner). If it isn't, remove the "kernel" word from the title.

Comment: @H2CO3 it is Kernel programming and if have to do it

Comment: well, in this case you don't really have any other choice...

Comment: @H2CO3 And what is the best way to find the information in the kernel stuff? looking in each file in the directory folder isn't that efficient

Comment: yes, it may not be, but I think reading the source itself is very useful. As others pointed it out, there are numerous tutorials and other kind of documentation about kernel programming in general and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The [Linux Kernel Newbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/) site is a good point to start.

And, of course, the kernel itself is the best reference. To get started. Also have a look at [kernel.org/doc](http://kernel.org/doc/). For semaphores, look at [this page here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/rusty/kernel-locking/c93.html).

Comment: Thanks, an other question by the way, should it bother me that I can not open the `man sem_wait` on my system but on another I can ?